# Getting the URL of the parent page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, ajax, jquery

I am developing a property listing site in which the link of the single property unit is often sent to the clients so now I need a "View Property Details" button on my single unit page which go back to the listings page of that respective property. Both the unit and property are the custom post types and there is a bidirectional relationship between both of them. Currently I am using the

```
window.history.back()
```

function on the click of the button but it behaves as the back button in the browser so if the client has come from his mail then the button will send him back to the gmail while I want to send him to the respective property in which that unit is listed. Also I tried using the dynamic value of "Archive" from the elementor but it is also not working. Any leads?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent post parent first

```
$parent_post = get_post_parent($post_id);
```

You can then retrieve the permalink of the parent post with

```
$parent_post->url
```

or with

```
get_permalink( $parent_post->ID )
```

Comment: But how do I tell that I have to get the parent post of the custom post type Unit. Do I need to add this piece of code in function.php or single.php